# How to map single JSON property to multiple objects using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, spring, oop, jackson

JSON

```
"user_number": 897798
```

Entity.java

```
@JsonProperty("user_number")
private String entityNumber;

@JsonProperty("user_number")
private Integer userNumber;
```

How do I map the single json property userNumber into both of the above-mentioned objects?
i.e. userNumber and entityNumber should have the same value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call setter of `entityNumber` from `userNumber` setter.

```
public static class Entity {

    private Integer entityNumber;

    @JsonProperty("user_number")
    private Integer userNumber;

    public Integer getEntityNumber() {
        return entityNumber;
    }
    public void setEntityNumber(Integer entityNumber) {
        this.entityNumber = entityNumber;
    }
    public Integer getUserNumber() {
        return userNumber;
    }
    public void setUserNumber(Integer userNumber) {
        this.userNumber = userNumber;
        setEntityNumber(userNumber);
    }
}
```

Now whenever `setUserNumber()` will be called, it will call `setEntityNumber()` as well.

Comment: This solution won't work when these two fields are of different types and the second field should be deserialized differently from the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to annotate both with `@JsonProperty("userNumber")`. This way both fields are mapped to the same field in json.

Comment: No it didn't work that way. The later one is set to null, only the first field is set with the value

Comment: Have you tried without this annotation over `userNumber`?

Comment: I have updated the question. can you please check again

Comment: It will not work, it will throw conflicting getter / setter for property `user_number`

Comment: @PratapiHemantPatel of course, because OP changed the question... I haven come up with improvement yet